# how to hide and unhide authoerable tabs depending upon value selected from a drop down in CQ5

Tags: aem

i am trying to create a footer component in CQ5, where i have 4 columns & all are autherable.
But we have to make no of columns autherable too i.e based on a value selected form a dropdown we have to open those many tabs for authoring those many columns only.

i have created a dropdown and have a maximum range of 6 columns. i know that i have to configure a listener for this purpose but don't know how . Requirement is like if i select 3 from the drop down then 3 tabs should come to author 3 columns

pls help me , i am middle of something very important.i need the solution very early too as i have to finish the job as soon as possible

Comment: What does your code for your `dialog.xml` look like & what errors are you getting? Presumably you've referenced the examples in the documentation before asking here? — http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/widgets.html#Example%201:%20Switch%20Tabs%20Dialog

Answer (score 1):

I might be late for this by now but in case you still need it:

You need to add a listener node before closing your drop-down element:

```
<listeners
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    loadcontent="function(box){ //here you also need to handle the hide/unhide when the panel loads for the first time. Use this.getValue() to retrive the intial value }"
    selectionchanged="function(box, value) { 
        for(var c=1;c<=value;c++){
            this.findParentByType('tabpanel').unhideTabStripItem("tab"+c); // You need to handle the opposite with hideTabStripItem("tab"+c);
        }
    }"/>
```

Then on both "loadcontent" and "selectionchange" (these are events on your drop-down) grab the current selected value and use it to hide/unhide the tabs. In this case the tabs would be named "tab1", "tab2", etc, make sure you get the names right.

The ExtJS in the events is finding the "tabpanel" container for the whole dialog, and then hiding/unhiding based on name. You could also set to enable/disable using the methods ".enable()" and ".setDisabled(true)". Just make sure you get the reference to the tab first if you want to do this (something like ".getComponent(tabName).enable()").

I didn't test this specific code, I couldn't find my actual example from my code base but this should take you in the right direction.